# ARKit - Issue with ARSession

Tags: ios11, augmented-reality, arkit, xcode9-beta

I'm trying to create `ARSession`, using ARKit with Xcode 9 beta (for iOS 11). But it seems not working properly.

Code I've tried is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // configure session
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

    // run session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}
```

Can anyone help? Code is almost correct according to Apple Documentation.

Comment: Which device are you trying this on? What does [ARSessionConfiguration. isSupported](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/2867255-issupported) return?

Comment: @vrwim I tried on my iPad mini 2 (A7 chip) and  ARSessionConfiguration is indeed supported. However, ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration is not and you cannot freely swap one with another.. it crashes the app

Comment: I tried running in iPad Air with ARSessionConfiguration and it still crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem with View controller's life cycle. According to apple guideline for ARSession, it Session can after you view is loaded completely. I mean, user view will appear to run your session.

Here is apple document for the same: [Building a Basic AR Experience](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/building_a_basic_ar_experience)

Also, look at following sample.

[image]

Comment: why isn't `viewDidLoad` a good method? View did load should be called when the view is loaded, right?

Answer (score 0):

ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration supports only iOS devices with an A9 processor or later.

As per Apple doc:

- On iOS devices with an A9 processor or later, the
  ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration
     subclass provides high-precision motion tracking and enables features to help you place virtual content in relation to real-world
  surfaces.
- On other devices supported by ARKit, the ARSessionConfiguration base
  class provides basic motion tracking that permits slightly less 
  immersive AR experiences.

iPhone and Processors:

```
 iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus has A8 processor.
 iPhone SE, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s plus has A9 processor.
 iPhone 7, iPhone 7plus has A10 processor
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem due to iOS11 beta1 bug, [iOS 11 Beta 1 Release Notes And Known Issues According To Apple](http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-11-beta-1-release-notes-changes-and-known-issues-according-to-apple/)

[image: snapsot image]

This means you need an iPhone 6S or better to use ARKit(ARSessionConfiguration) at the current time. Until the iOS11 beta2 release...

> 2017.07.13 update

My iphone6 had update to iOS11 beta3, and it can run ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration, amazing!

> 2017.09.07 update

iphone6 can not run ARWorldTrackingConfiguration in recently iOS11 beta...... :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to also initialize a SCNScene and add it to the ARSCNView.

```
let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
```

I usually do this before I set up the session too.